# How do I get a value from another UIView with XIB file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have two XIB files.The first one with my app view and then the user can fill with required informations. The second is a form and the user can start typing some name and my table view will be like a autofill field.

The question is, how can I open the second view allowing the user to do his research and after that send the user back to another screen with the selected information?

Comment: Take a look at the master-detail template in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this data in many ways..

1) You can use ur singleton data class, to handle to & from data.

2) You can use appDelegate handle the data.

3) You can have data object say `NSDictionary` so that open exit from second view, data is sent to first view.

In my opinion use the third option, have a method in first view like..

```
-(void)setData(NSDictionary*)data
{
enter code here
}
```

set the data, and set the pointer of first view to second view, while `alloc` and presenting the second view.

On exiting the second view, using that pointer send the data using that method..

Comment: I got it! I will try using that, looks good idea. Thanks so much